# Trigger jQuery Popup box on certain day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just added a jQuery box to my company website using the tutorial over at [queness.com](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial)

For example:

- 31st of October - display Halloween image
- 5th November fireworks image
- 25th December display happy masochist image

etc.

but I want to expand on this and have the popup window only display at certain times of the year. Basically its just a simple "happy 'insert holiday' " image to our customers.When its not a specific date just want website to display as standard with no popup box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TGQXc/

```
var today = new Date();
var first = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
var theDay = Math.round(((today - first) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) + .5, 0);

if (theDay == 298)alert("It is day 298! Yahtzee!")
```

Use this method do get the day of the year and test it against specific days.

Today is the 298th day of the year, and as you can see, I have theDay tested against 298 with success.

So just use this test for each box like so:

```
if (theDay == 359){ //Christmas day
    //Your code
}
```

You'll just need to calculate which day of the year is each date you want.

Comment: Why are you working out the day of the year? Surely it's better to compare against the day/month? Also, with a leap year your method will be more complicated.

Comment: That leap year thing is a good point, but other than that it works. Just helping him step in the right direction.

Comment: It may work, but it's a lot less confusing to compare the day/month rather than the number of days elapsed in the year.

Comment: thanks Joel much appreciated, for now it works as for leap year i have 4 years to learn how to compare the day/month rather then number of days.